# How to compare two artifactory npm repositories

Tags: npm, artifactory, enterprise

Given two Artifactory repositories that are ultimately mirrors of the main npm repo, but with one being a filtered view that only has security-scanned dependencies within it, what would be the best way to diff the available packages and versions in each one?

**EDIT:** To further clarify, the result would be the ability to browse the available packages and versions in each one, and especially where there were different versions available.

Comment: `package-lock.json`?

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but I'm looking for an ability to see which versions and packages are available in each one, and especially where they're different.